# iPhone App Linking

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, web-applications

I am working on this app that works similarly to the iPhone contact list.

http://fixmysite.us/bobapp/indexnew.html

For some reason, it only seems to work in Chrome/Safari and iOs simulator.

How do I use javascript, like onclick, to make it so when I click a name, it calls like "firstName" + .html to get the page for the name selected.

for example if i click on bob, it slides over to bob.html.

Is this the way i should be doing it or is there a better way?

Thanks so much in advance.